# Matrix Trace Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, trace

If $\operatorname{Tr}(A) < \operatorname{Tr}(B)$, is it fair to say that $\operatorname{Tr}(AC) < \operatorname{Tr}(BC)$? All of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are positive definite matrices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. The OP could have carried out a computational experiment to verify the conjecture first.

Comment: @anu cex easy inequality with trace: for all symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ we have $Tr(ABAB)\leq Tr(A^2B^2)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1.1 \end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} 1.2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you conclude anything?